# Can I override generic properties declared with a protocol in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, inheritance, overriding

Would such an approach be fine in Swift or is it a bad idea:

```
protocol Serializable {
    func serealize()
}

class SomeBaseVC: UIViewController {

    var serialisableObject: Serializable?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        serialisableObject?.serealize()
        //Do some other generic stuff with serialisableObject
    }

}

class JSONObject: Serializable {
    func serealize() {
        //serealize
    }


}

class SomeChildVCWhichHasSomeGenericBehaviour: SomeBaseVC {
    override var serialisableObject: JSONObject

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() //Now this would do serealisation of JSONObject
        //And now do something specific to just this VC
    }
}
```

So the point is to have some generic behavior that is shared by many of my view controllers implemented in my superclass using protocols. Say I have a lot of view controllers that need to serialize some object and save it in viewDidLoad method (this is obviously a hypothetical example). This could be a some JSON data or some XML data. Now I could everytime implement a different viewDidLoad method, depending on whether controller is working with XML or JSON, but as shown above I think I can encapsulate it in the base class, then I could just inherit from this base VC and just call super.viewDidLoad(). The only part that bothers me is:

```
override var serialisableObject: JSONObject
```

Am I allowed to do that? Is that a good idea?

Comment: You haven't shown the superclass of `SomeChildVCWhichHasSomeGenericBehaviour` but I assume you want it to be `SomeBaseVC` - In this case you cannot change the type of `serialisableObject` since that would violate the LSP - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle.  You can just try your code in a Playground and you will see the error that you cannot redefine `serialisableObject`

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, you are right, it is SomeBaseVC. Any idea how I would achieve such behaviour?

Comment: You can assign any object that conforms to `Serializable` to the property and `serialisableObject?.serealize()` will call the appropriate function.  What it does mean is that in your view controller subclass you would need to downcast the property when you wanted to refer to it as the specific type

Comment: @Paulw11 that is a solution, but that feels kind of wrong. Is there a more general problem with how I am structuring my classes and protocols? Because if I don't do that, then I am clearly rewriting the same code a lot of times. If I do not, then I am doing something weird, downcasting my object every time I want to use it

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the type of serialisableObject since that would violate the [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

You can use a setter/getter to effectively alias another property in your subclass to the superclass `serialisableObject` property.  This would allow you to use the specific type in your view controller subclass whilst the superclass would use the alias:

```
class SomeChildVCWhichHasSomeGenericBehaviour: SomeBaseVC {

    var jsonThing: JSONObject?

    override var serialisableObject: Serializable? {
        get {
            return jsonThing
        }

        set {
            self.jsonThing = newValue as? JSONObject
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() //Now this would do de-serealisation of JSONObject
        print(self.jsonThing) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this approach actually used or is this a bad practice and I should reconsider how I use protocol-oriented programming?